# html5video Cordova android plugin won't install error using CLI

Tags: android, cordova, html5-video, phonegap-plugins

Using the CLI to install the plugin an error appears:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video.git
Failed to install 'jaeger.Html5Video':Error: Expected fetched plugin to have ID "org.apache.cordova.device" but got "cordova-plugin-device".
    at checkID (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:163:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:147:9
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
Error: Expected fetched plugin to have ID "org.apache.cordova.device" but got "cordova-plugin-device".
    at checkID (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:163:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:147:9
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I installed the plugin without issue

```
$ cordova -v
4.3.0

$ cordova plugin
jaeger.Html5Video 1.2.1 "Html5Video"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0 "Device"
```

The latest cordova cli version 5.0 includes some breaking changes. The core plugins are now [available through npm](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html), and their ids [have been modified](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-plugin-device.git;a=blobdiff;f=plugin.xml;h=d3739411cedf0704e28669761cbebbc593a01410;hp=160f4dcd7ca566971b6d123179785c5318798152;hb=HEAD;hpb=a58233693cb8b21ba243e225c64d9a4af2ad61d7) to follow npm conventions. `org.apache.cordova.device` has become `cordova-plugin-device`. I'm guessing this is your issue

In the HTML5Video git repo, the [plugin.xml](https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video/blob/master/plugin.xml) specifies a dependency with the old id.

```
<dependency id="org.apache.cordova.device" url="https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git" commit="master" subdir="." />
```

I am guessing you have cordova-cli 5.0 installed and finding the latest version of the device dependency with the new `cordova-plugin-device` id.

The HTML5Video plugin.xm needs to update the id of the device dependency. You can fork the HTML5Videp repo and update the dependency

```
<dependency id="cordova-plugin-device" url="https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git" commit="master" subdir="." />
```

then do

```
cordova plugin add http://url/to/your/repo/Html5Video.git
```

You might alternatively be able to specify a version on the repo url to get the version of the device plugin that the HTML5Video plugin expects

```
<dependency id="org.apache.cordova.device" url="https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git@0.3.0" commit="master" subdir="." />
```

Comment: You might also be able to downgrade to cordova-cli to install the proper package. npm uninstall cordova -g && npm install cordova@4.3 -g